# file_get_contents(): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm making a multiple images upload system in php.
This is what I have:

**PHP**

```
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $name_tmp)
{
        $name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
        $size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($name));

        $query2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO afbeeldingen(naam, afbeelding) values ('$name', '$image')");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
```

Now if I add one or more files via the input form, I get the following error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(download (1).jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Apps\Xampp\htdocs\el_gusto\toevoegen_handler.php on line 578
```

What I'm I doing wrong?
I'm only inserting the name & image for now.

Thanks in advance and taking time to read this!

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$tmp_name` when calling `file_get_contents()`. This is the actual location of the file on disk until the end of the request. `$name` contains the original name of the uploaded file in case you need it.

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem!

Comment: If it solved your problem, please accept the answer.